# Does the SQL Server Agent affect the performance of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Does the SQL Server Agent affect the performance of SQL Server?

Do I need to stop it to increase SQL Server speed!

If yes, please give me more details

Comment: If the agent is **running** a job - then yes, the server performance will be affected, of course - since something is running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Server Agent is a service which executes any jobs you have configured on the server. It will not inherently affect performance itself, as it's not running most of the time.

When it runs a job, the performance hit will be identical to if you were running the items in the job yourself.

If you were to disable it, you wouldn't be able to run any jobs. Probably not a great idea.